# How to reduce php-fpm memory usage? Is it possible to remove some PHP extensions?

Tags: php, virtualmin

My centos 6.7 server has only my php and mysql based websites using nginx web server and virtualmin (no wordpress or external scripts/software).

I installed PHP with :

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 install -y php-mysqlnd php-fpm
```

yum installed dependencies like php-commom, php-pdo etc.

I checked the running processes in my server using virtualmin.

**each php-fpm: pool www** process is using around **400MB** memory.

There are more than 20 extensions in etc/php.d directory.

[image: php-extensions in etc/php.d directory]

I commented most of the extensions in etc/php.d directory.

I checked the installed extensions using

```
<?php
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>

[0] => Core
[1] => date
[2] => ereg
[3] => libxml
[4] => openssl
[5] => pcre
[6] => zlib
[7] => filter
[8] => hash
[9] => Reflection
[10] => SPL
[11] => session
[12] => standard
[13] => cgi-fcgi
[14] => curl
[15] => ftp
[16] => mysqlnd
[17] => PDO
[18] => mysql
[19] => pdo_mysql
[20] => json
[21] => mhash
```

after restarting php-fpm and nginx, 
**each php-fpm: pool www** process is using around **200MB** memory.

Is it possible to disable some more extensions like ereg, libxml, Reflection, SPL, mhash etc ?

I hope this will reduce some more RAM usage by each of php-fpm: pool www processes.

Please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might have better luck over at [server.fault](http://serverfault.com/) while this is about "php" it's not really about programming.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I am very sorry for posting it here! shall I post this question again in serverfault ? or can anybody move it to serverfault? Thanks.

Comment: Hi! It was not meant as criticism, (as I'm not certain whether it's more appropriate over there), but I figured that 1. your question **might** get closed. 2. You might get better / faster answers over there. Although you should properly read their help section / on-topic before posting.

Comment: You can reduce "memory_limit", 128M (default value) is very high, usually 32M should be enough. Some extensions (like date, reflection, spl...) cannot be disabled, must always be there.